# NLTK issue in deriving sql query using fcfg

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, information-extraction

I'm using NLTK to get sql query from english text using feature based cfg. I followed this link http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html. I can run the example stated where fcfg is stored in the sql0.fcfg file.

After that I tried to modify it for my own use where I added a following new set of rules:

```
% start S
## Added by me
S[SEM=(?whadvp + ?sq)] -> WHADVP[SEM=?whadvp] SQ[SEM=?sq]

WHADVP[SEM=(?wrb + ?jj)] -> WRB[SEM=?wrb] JJ[SEM=?jj]
SQ[SEM=(?vbp + ?np + ?vp)] -> VBP[SEM=?vbp] NP[SEM=?np] VP[SEM=?vp]
NP[SEM=(?np + ?pp)] -> NP[SEM=?np] PP[SEM=?pp]
NP[SEM=(?np)] -> JJS[SEM=?jjs]
VP[SEM=(?vbz + ?advp)] -> VBZ[SEM=?vbz] ADVP[SEM=?advp]
PP[SEM=(?in + ?np)] -> IN[SEM=?in] NP[SEM=?np]
NP[SEM=(?prp + ?nn)] -> PRP$[SEM=?prp] NN[SEM=?nn]
ADVP[SEM=(?rb)] -> RB[SEM=?rb]

WRB[SEM='SELECT average(calldurationinsexonds) FROM Task'] -> 'How'

JJ[SEM=''] -> 'long'
VBP[SEM=''] -> 'do'
JJS[SEM=''] -> 'most'
IN[SEM=''] -> 'of'
PRP$[SEM=''] -> 'our'
NN[SEM=''] -> 'phone'
VBZ[SEM=''] -> 'calls'
JJ[SEM=''] -> 'last'

## Default example
S[SEM=(?np + WHERE + ?vp)] -> NP[SEM=?np] VP[SEM=?vp]

VP[SEM=(?v + ?pp)] -> IV[SEM=?v] PP[SEM=?pp]
VP[SEM=(?v + ?ap)] -> IV[SEM=?v] AP[SEM=?ap]
NP[SEM=(?det + ?n)] -> Det[SEM=?det] N[SEM=?n]
PP[SEM=(?p + ?np)] -> P[SEM=?p] NP[SEM=?np]
AP[SEM=?pp] -> A[SEM=?a] PP[SEM=?pp]

NP[SEM='Country="greece"'] -> 'Greece'
NP[SEM='Country="china"'] -> 'China'

Det[SEM='SELECT'] -> 'Which' | 'What'

N[SEM='City FROM city_table'] -> 'cities'

IV[SEM=''] -> 'are'
A[SEM=''] -> 'located'
P[SEM=''] -> 'in'
```

After saving the file, when I execute following commands I run into errors

```
cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
query = 'How long do most of our phone calls last'
trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\chart.py",
>   line 1350, in parse
>       chart = self.chart_parse(tokens)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\chart.py", line 1309, in
>   chart_parse
>       self._grammar.check_coverage(tokens)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\grammar.py", line 631, in
>   check_coverage
>       "input words: %r." % missing) ValueError: Grammar does not cover some of the input words: u"'How', 'long', 'do', 'most',  'of', 'our',
>   'phone', 'calls', 'last'".

I don't know if there is a mistake in my added grammar or some other issue. Any help or suggestion would be great.

Comment: "Grammar does not cover some of the input words"

Comment: This grammar would generate a complete SQL by encountering the single word 'How', thanks to rule WRB. It is returned to its parent rule WHADVP via the variable ?wrb. If the input is 'How long' the variable ?jj has the value '' according to rule JJ. The other words in the input also maps to an empty SEM. It doesn't look like a proper grammar to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was modifying the \grammars\book_grammars\sql0.fcfg. When I saved it as separate file and loaded grammar from there, the problem got solved.

Don't know why it happened, but it resolved the issue.

Comment: I have a similar issue as this. Can you take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770861/loading-and-editing-a-cfg-file-for-grammar-parsing